# Android - Expandable View control

Tags: android, xamarin, expandable

I am looking for a Expandable control for Android. I do not mean Expandable List View though. I wonder if there is already such a control as for example the one that is used in BBC iRadio that slides in and out a view.

But in this case I need a control that will rather expand and collapse.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using this nice little library: [Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)